# Error in the script for generating 2D rectangles

Tags: python, scripting, error

I tried to run the script below in Blender 3.6, which errors out with message:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shift\Downloads\generate_200rectangles_in square2019.blend\Text", line 51, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\shift\Downloads\blender-3.6.0-windows-x64\3.6\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 113, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "radius" unrecognized
```

Can you please correct this error knowing that the script is working with Blender 2.79

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
from random import random

def check_plane_bounbox( planC, planR1, planR2, rectC, rectR ):
    ''' Make sure this circle does not protrude outside the rectangle bounding box '''
    maxX = rectC.x + rectR
    minX = rectC.x - rectR
    maxY = rectC.y + rectR
    minY = rectC.y - rectR

    withinX = ( planC.x + planR1 <= maxX ) and ( planC.x - planR1 >= minX )
    withinX = ( planC.x + planR2 <= maxX ) and ( planC.x - planR2 >= minX )
    withinY = ( planC.y + planR2 <= maxY ) and ( planC.y - planR2 >= minY )
    withinY = ( planC.y + planR1 <= maxY ) and ( planC.y - planR1 >= minY )

    return withinX and withinY

def check_overlap( planes, planC, planR1, planR2 ):
    ''' Make sure the distance between the current circle's center
        and all others circle centers is greater than or equal to the circle radius
    '''
    return len( [ True for c in planes if ( c - planC ).length >= planR1 * 1 and ( c - planC ).length >= planR2 * 1 ] ) == len( planes )
    #return len( [ True for c in planes if ( c - planC ).length >= planR1 * 2 and ( c - planC ).length >= planR2 * 2 ] ) == len( planes )

size1 = 0.00025
size2 = 0.01
planeCount  = 200
rectCenter   = Vector((0, 0, 0))
rectRadius   = 0.1

planes = []

maxIterations = 1000000

z = 0 # All circles lie on Z = 0
i = 0
while len( planes ) < planeCount and i < maxIterations:
    x, y = [ 2 * rectRadius * random() - rectRadius for axis in 'xy' ]
    planC = Vector((x, y, z ))

    if check_plane_bounbox( planC, size1, size2, rectCenter, rectRadius ) \
       and check_overlap( planes, planC, size1, size2 ):
           planes.append( planC )

    i += 1

for c in planes:
    #bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add( radius = circleRadius, location = c )
    #bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(location=c, radius= circleRadius, vertices=12, fill_type='NGON')
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius = 1, location=c)#Matpi
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(size1, size2, 0), constraint_axis=(False, False, False))#Matpi
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=random())
```

Also, how to add a freestyle square that outlines rectangles.

Displaying results with Blender 2.79:
[image]

Comment: `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add` no `radius` keyword can use. use `size` instead. You can go here to see what keywords are available:  https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add

Comment: @saded as mentioned by X Y, change the line `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius = 1, location=c)` to `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=1, location=c)` then it will run.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I still have to put these rectangles in a square, how do I add that in the script. [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPZFF.png